# How to TEXTJOIN in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, concatenate

I have ten columns in my rows which contain 5 sets of first name/last name. I want to combine each of these names in a final column using `TEXTJOIN` (or whatever function is appropriate if I'm missing something).

I tried this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", true, W2 & " " & X2,Y2 & " " & Z2,AA2 & " " & AB2,AC2 & " " & AD2,AE2 & " " & AF2)
```

But if I don't have some names in the 2nd or 3rd or 4th or 5th sets, then it will come back with `Jerry Jackson, , , ,`

I'd like to do the conditionals and add the commas where appropriate, but all of my modifications include the commas.

Please help.

Comment: only one row or whole range in one row or whole range to respective rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(", ", 
 W2&" "&X2,Y2&" "&Z2,AA2&" "&AB2,AC2&" "&AD2,AE2&" "&AF2), 
 " ,", "")), "^,|,$", "")
```

[image: 0]